# How to use setInterval with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I want the following app to print *DAnce* every second on the screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Sample extends React.Component {
    sample(text, i) {
        return <h1> DAnce</h1>;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="text-intro" id="site-type">  
                {setInterval(()=>this.sample('igod',1),1000)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Sample />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Instead I get **5** printed on the screen.
How do I obtain the desired effect?

Comment: Do you want to render more and more `Dance` every second?

Comment: Yes sir. One after another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store a `count` in your state, and use an interval to increment this `count` every second and create `count` many `Dance` in the render method.

**Example**

```js
class Sample extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return { count: previousState.count + 1 };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-intro" id="site-type">
        {Array.from({ length: this.state.count }, () => <div>Dance</div>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Sample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to think has the text as something that is changing in your app. That is ideal for state.

I don't know what your functions sample does. But let's say you have it declared.

```
const sample = (text, i) => { ... };
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
class Sample extends Component {
  state = {
    text: sample('igod', 1),
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        text: this.sample('igod',1)
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-intro" id="site-type">
        {this.state.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically what happens is, when your component mounts you will start a timeout where every 1 second it will update the state thus updating your UI.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Sample extends React.Component {
sample(text, i) {
    return <h1> DAnce</h1>;
}
   render(){
      return(
         <div className="text-intro" id="site-type">
         {setTimeout(()=>{this.sample('igod',1)}, 1000)}
         </div>
      );
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <Sample />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have used setTimeout which will be called only number of times while component renders.
>
> You need to use setInterval to work each second.

Replace with this. Hopw this will help you.

```
{setInterval(()=>this.sample('igod',1),1000)}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the react [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#lifecycle-methods):

```js
export class Sample extends React.Component {
sample(text, i) {
        this.setState({ text });
}
render(){
    return(
        <div className="text-intro" id="site-type">
            <h1>{this.state.text}</h1>
            {setTimeout(()=>this.sample('igod',1),1000)}
        </div>
    );
}
```